# ¿Porque mi aplicación de android al ejecutar el .apk me muestra todas mis activities por separado?

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi problema es que creo un archivo de tipo .apk en mi android studio y le digo que se ejecute en mi celular y pues si me manda la aplicación funcional, pero yo tengo 11 activities en mi carpeta layout y esas mismas 11 activities las puedo ver en mi celular, por lo que cada vez que ejecuto la .apk desde android studio hacia mi teléfono se generan las 12 activities por separado. ¿Como resuelvo este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero tu captura te está mostrando la descarga de la apk, normal que tengas multiples siempre se crean app.apk app(1).apk.... pero eso es diferente que tengas la app en memoria N veces.

Comment: @webserveis y no se podría hacer que solamente me apareciera una .apk sin necesidad de que se vean las otras, como cuando descargo una app de play store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa en el Manifest de tu aplicación que al declarar los activities no tengas algo como esto en cada activity declarado.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Elimina esas lineas y deja solo algo como esto para cada activity

```
<activity android:name="com.app.Activity1"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

David, lo que se ve en tu imagen parecen ser descargas, cuando descargas un .apk puedes descargar el mismo archivo generando una nueva copia por esa razón ves varias aplicaciones.

---

#### De cualquier forma agrego 2 situaciones que pudieran generar varias aplicaciones instaladas.

Un problema puede ser que en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` todas tus Activity tienen definido el filtro cin action MAIN y  category LAUNCHER :

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Unicamente una Activity puede estar definida de esta forma.

---

Otra causa es que al generar tu aplicación, esta tenga un nombre de paquete (package name) diferente, debido a esto al instalar podrías estar instalando una aplicación que se considera nueva para el sistema operativo.